# Substitute variable as an input from the STDOUT of a console application

Tags: cmd, tfs, azure-devops, variable-substitution

In our release pipeline, we have a console app that performs a function which generates an encryption key and outputs it to STDOUT. We need to be able to use this value in a variable during deployment (updating a configuration file with the results from the console app). We've tried using the Output Variables option in the command line task in Azure Devops but unfortunately we need it in a different format... and it just doesn't seem to work as expected.

E.g. Our cmd line tool outputs `908321093RANDOMLYGENERATEDKEY3422543` to STDOUT

The name in our config file for that key is something like `Settings.Security.OurKey` however the output variable in the command line task does not allow periods (.) and as such is set to `SettingsSecurityOurKey`... we've also tried SETTINGS_SECURITY_OURKEY, but the variable value is never set by the task.

Is it possible to somehow set the Azure Devops variable to the value of the output variable from the command line or a powershell script? Something like:

```
set $(Settings.Security.OurKey) = SettingsSecurityOurKey
```

Or is there a simpler method of achieving this? It seems like it shouldn't be that difficult..

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Powershell issue rather than an issue with Azure DevOps.

```
# Variable name with special characters
$VariableName.That.Contains.Periods     # This will NOT work.
${VariableName.That.Contains.Periods}   # This will work.
```

Refer this for more information: https://blog.danskingdom.com/accessing-powershell-variables-with-periods-in-their-name/

Comment: OP is hoping to set the STDOUT from the command line app as the variable value... I think what you're suggesting is how to use a variable on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a PowerShell variable to contain the standard output from a command, just assign it:

```
$yourVariableName = your_command_that_writes_to_stdout
```

If the output is only one line, the PowerShell variable will contain a single string; otherwise it will contain an array.